# How to select an image inside a link inside of a list-element with a class attribute with jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, list, thumbnails

I have following problem: I got a dynamically generated list of thumbnails where i can't give the images neither a class nor an id-attribut. The list looks like this:

```
<div id="list">
        <ul id="clips">
            <li class="inactive"><a href=""><img src="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3731/buddyicons/30470506@N05.jpg?1377890675#30470506@N05"/></a></li>
            <li class="inactive"><a href=""><img src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7406/9704752996_361b1f64a7_s.jpg"/></a></li>
            <li class="inactive"><a href=""><img src="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5545/9703755774_818c649c7c_s.jpg"/></a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href=""><img src="http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2892/buddyicons/98149247@N02.jpg?1377034353#98149247@N02"/></a></li>                
        </ul>
</div>
```

As you can see has one list element the class attribute "active". i gave this one another style than the others. But i want the previous and the next picture to have different styles as well. Now is the question: How to select them?

I was experimenting a bit and was able to select the previous and the next list element and could change their styles. The Code for it was:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('li.active').prev().css('background-color', 'red');
            $('li.active').prev().css('height', '300px');
            $('li.active').next().css('background-color', 'red');
            $('li.active').next().css('height', '300px');
       });
    </script>
```

That worked for the list elements. But i need to select the images. Unfortunately "li.active img" didnt work and unfortunately i am not able to change the php-code so that the images will have a class name. So is there a way to select that two images and change their styles with jquery?

Regards

Comment: Try "li.active a img"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any of the following

Simply add Class to image

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $('li.active').prev().find('img').addClass('previmg');
        $('li.active').next().find('img').addClass('nextimg');
   });
```

By this way you can use new image classes for identify jquery clicks

Or Try this

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $('li.active').prev().find('img').css({
                                    background-color: 'red', 
                                    height : '300px'
        });
        $('li.active').next().find('img').css({
                                    background-color: 'red', 
                                    height : '300px'
        });
   });
```

Or you can use a long way

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $('li.active').prev().children('a').children('img').css({
                                          background-color: 'red', 
                                          height : '300px'
        });
        $('li.active').next().children('a').children('img').css({
                                          background-color: 'red', 
                                          height : '300px'
        });
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

add .find(img) and it will find the img inside of the li.active, something like :

```
$('li.active').find(img).whatever...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery's `.addClass();` function to add a class to the previous and next `li`s and then style the images within them with CSS.

See http://jsfiddle.net/TFQ3K/3/